# Uploading an image to Firebase with React-Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I'm using this method to try upload image to Firebase with my React-Native app because it seems to be a very common example on the internet, However I think it is quite old and I suspect that it no longer works on newer versions of React-Native.

Can someone please show me the correct way to save images in Firebase storage, thank you!

```
 const uploadImage = (uri, imageName, mime = 'image/jpg') => { 

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') 
  : uri;
      let uploadBlob = null
      const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/').child(imageName)
      fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
        .then((data) => {
          return Blob.build(data, {type: `${mime};BASE64`})
        })
        .then((blob) => {
          uploadBlob = blob
          return imageRef.put(blob, {contentType: mime})
        })
        .then(() => {
          uploadBlob.close()
          return imageRef.getDownloadURL()
        })
        .then((url) => {
          resolve(url)
        })
        .catch((error) =>{reject(error)})
    })
}
```

Comment: You should add some details about why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the putFile method.

Here is my FirebaseStorageService with saveImage method (I'm using RN 0.53 and react-native-firebase 4.1.0):

```
saveImage(ref, image, imageName, onSuccess, onError){
    LOG.debug("FirebaseStorageService :: saveImage ", {ref:ref, image:image, imageName:imageName});

    var firebaseStorageRef = firebase.storage().ref(ref);
    const imageRef = firebaseStorageRef.child(imageName + ".jpeg");

    LOG.debug("FirebaseStorageService :: imageRef ", {imageRef:imageRef});


    imageRef.putFile(image.path, {contentType: 'image/jpeg'}).then(function(){
        return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
    }).then(function(url){
        LOG.debug("Image url", {url:url});
        onSuccess(url);
    }).catch(function(error){
        LOG.error("Error while saving the image.. ", error);
        onError(error);
    });
}
```

The image is the one returned by [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker). User can choose between open camera and open gallery and it returns an image object.

The path property of the image object is just a string like "file://.." for Android and "/Users/..." for iOS.

Comment: Thank you. It working perfectly. Easiest method for image uploading.